# Problema con Operadores de Comparación MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedimiento el cual no se por que pero a la hora de compilarlo me da error en el operador de comparación. He probado con distintos operadores NOT LIKE (ya que lo que compara es un VARCHAR) también e probado con los comparadores numéricos <>, != pero todos me dan error.
Dejo mi código aquí, solo salta el error del los operadores de comparación de nada mas debería ser con NOT LIKE ya que lo que esta comparando es una cadena de texto VARCHAR pero no funciona.

El mensaje de error que me muestra es el seiguiente: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1byteIP NOT LIKE 1byteGW) AND (2byteIP NOT LIKE 2byteGW) THEN
SE' at line 27
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  CONFIGURACION;

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE  CONFIGURACION(IN ipv4 VARCHAR(15), IN mascara VARCHAR(15),
                                      IN puerta VARCHAR(15), OUT mensaje TEXT)

BEGIN
     DECLARE 1byteIP INT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 1byteGW INT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE caracteres INT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 2byteIP INT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 2byteGW INT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE resultado TEXT DEFAULT '';
     
     SET mensaje = 'La configuracion IPv4: \n\n';


     IF mascara NOT IN ('255.0.0.0','255.255.0.0','255.255.255.0') THEN
          SET resultado = '    ERROR. No a introducido una mascara correcta, solo se admiten las
                                             direcciones 255.0.0.0, 255.255.0.0 y 255.255.255.0';
     ELSE 
          SET 1byteIP = (select substring(ipv4,1,locate(".",ipv4)-1));
          SET 1byteGW = (select substring(puerta,1,locate(".",puerta)-1));
          SET caracteres = (select LENGTH(substring(ipv4,1,locate(".",ipv4)+1)));
          SET 2byteIP = (select substring(ipv4,caracteres,locate(".",ipv4)-1));
          SET 2byteGW = (select substring(puerta,caracteres,locate(".",puerta)-1));


          IF mascara NOT IN ('255.0.0.0','255.255.0.0','255.255.255.0') THEN
          SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,'    ERROR!! No a introducido una mascara correcta, solo se admiten las
                                            direcciones 255.0.0.0, 255.255.0.0 y 255.255.255.0');
          ELSE (1byteIP NOT LIKE 1byteGW) OR (2byteIP NOT LIKE 2byteGW) THEN 
               SET resultado = 'error no coinciden los los digitos de la direccion IPv4 con los de la puerta de enlace |';
          ELSE (1byteIP < 10) AND (2byteIP < 255) AND (mascara = '255.0.0.0') THEN 
             SET resultado = 'Es CORRECTA |';
          ELSE (1byteIP = 172) AND (2byteIP > 16) AND (2byteIP < 31) AND (mascara = '255.255.0.0') THEN 
             SET resultado = 'Es CORRECTA |';
          ELSE (1byteIP = 169) AND (2byteIP = 254) AND (mascara = '255.255.0.0') THEN 
             SET resultado = 'Es CORRECTA |';
          ELSE (1byteIP = 192) AND (2byteIP = 168) AND (mascara = '255.255.255.0') THEN 
             SET resultado = 'Es CORRECTA |';
          ELSE 
               SET resultado = 'La Mascara no cuincide con la direccion IPv4 |';

          END IF;

     END IF;

     SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,'Con direccion IPv4   --> ',ipv4,'\n');
     SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,'Con mascara de red   --> ',mascara,'\n');        
     SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,'Con puerta de enlace  --> ',puerta,'\n \n'); 
     SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,resultado); 


END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega  tu pregunta los mensajes de error que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando el metodo STRCMP(str1, str2). Este método retorna 0 si los strings comparados son iguales, 1 o -1 dependiendo si no.

```
STRCMP(1byteIP, 1byteGW) <> 0 --1byteIP NOT LIKE 1byteGW
STRCMP(2byteIP, 2byteGW) <> 0 --2byteIP NOT LIKE 2byteGW
```